# Django : How to use message_dict attribute of ValidationError?

Tags: django, model-validation, validationerror

I am trying to catch the error message of model validation and then send it to
the template by context variable to print it on webpage. But cannot do it. 
I read the django material that say try to use message_dict attribute of
ValidationError but cannot find the nice example for that.

(the django reference
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)

Here below is part of my code.

```
        try:
            user.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:

            email_error_message = e.message_dict['email']
            nickname_error_message = e.message_dict['nickname']

            return render(request, 'welcome/register.html', {'email_error_message' :   
                 email_error_message, 'nickname_error_message' : nickname_error_message})
```

How could I make it possible? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The message_dict value is a list of error messages, not just a single error message, so you need should join the messages.

```
try:
    user.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:

    email_error_message = ','.join(e.message_dict['email'])
    nickname_error_message = ', '.join(e.message_dict['nickname'])

    return render(request, 'welcome/register.html', {'email_error_message' :   
         email_error_message, 'nickname_error_message' : nickname_error_message})
```